# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment when using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I execute following line of code inside function I get an exception: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` but using the same line of code outside of function runs without any error. Why is that?

```
result = [{'year': 1990, 'days_in_mon':'1,2'}, {'year':1991, 'days_in_mon':'2,3'}]

def test_fn(li):
  return [int(i) for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",") for x in li if x['year'] == 1991]

test_fn(result) # Gives an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

[int(i) for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",") for x in result if x['year'] == 1991] # No Error
```

#### update

Expected result : [2,3]

#### What am I trying to do here?

I am trying to pull out value of of 'days_in_mon' from certain dict in a list and parse it as a list of numbers.

Comment: check this [int(i) for x in a if x['a'] == 2 for i in x['b'].split(",") ]

Comment: what are u doing with nested loop ?

Comment: @pdshah I've updated my question to be more clear at what am I trying to do and what am I trying to achieve.

Comment: both `[int(i) for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",") for x in result if x['year'] == 1991]` and `[int(i) for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",") for x in li if x['year'] == 1991]` are same and raising exception inside and outside of function. @Igle's answer is correct. You have wrong implementation of list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn around your loops in the list comprehension:

```
 result = [{'year': 1990, 'days_in_mon':'1,2'}, {'year':1991, 'days_in_mon':'2,3'}]

 def test_fn(li):
   return [int(i) for x in li if x['year'] == 1991 for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",")]

 test_fn(result)

 # returns [2, 3]
```

This is needed, as the first loop is evaluated before the second. So x must be initialized before executing the second one.

The way you wrote it, x is not defined:

```
print [int(i) for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",") for x in result if x['year'] == 1991]
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

what u have:

```
[int(i) for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",") for x in result if x['year'] == 1991]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    [int(i) for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",") for x in result if x['year'] == 1991]
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

what to be :

```
>>> [int(i) for x in result if x['year'] == 1991 for i in x['days_in_mon'].split(",") ]
[2, 3]
```

you write the nested loop in wrong way